# Keep receiving "HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests" with any delay

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

A simple web scraping code I wrote few weeks back keeps coming up with the error of:
HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
The code is designed to get the input from an excel file and find and download pdfs online.
I'm not too familiar with requests but I've slowed down the number of requests to see how many it can handle. It seems to be an unrelated issue somehow. The code will go through similar number of inputs (around 30) no matter if the delays I sat are at 5 seconds or 20 seconds. Here is the error message that keeps coming up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\New folder\Web Scraper.py", line 17, in <module>
    for url in search(searchquery, stop=1, pause=2):
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\google-2.0.2-py3.7.egg\googlesearch\__init__.py", line 288, in search
    html = get_page(url, user_agent)
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\google-2.0.2-py3.7.egg\googlesearch\__init__.py", line 154, in get_page
    response = urlopen(request)
  File "D:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "D:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "D:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "D:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "D:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "D:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "D:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "D:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "D:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

And here is the code that I wrote:

```
import xlrd, requests
from googlesearch import search
from time import sleep

xlloc = ("D:/VesselBase.xlsx")
#Excel location
ws = xlrd.open_workbook(xlloc)
sheet = ws.sheet_by_index(0)
#Sheet name/index
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    vesselname = sheet.cell_value(i, 1)
    vesselimo = sheet.cell_value(i,0)
    #Which column/row to choose, 2nd column for vessels. 0=A/1.
    searchquery = 'Vessel specification information "%s" OR "%s" filetype:pdf' % (vesselname, vesselimo)
    print('Searching "%s"' % searchquery)
    for url in search(searchquery, stop=1, pause=20):
        print('Searched for %s' % vesselname)
        print('Found %s' % url)
        open('D:/Newfolder/%s.pdf' % vesselname, 'wb').write(requests.get(url).content)
        #Where to save
        print('Saved %s' % vesselname)
```

Comment: You see those when you exceed a rate limit

Comment: I know that, but surely 20 seconds per request is plenty time to be above the rate limit?

Comment: apparently not.

Comment: is there something else I can use? I've even tried 120 seconds to no avail.

Comment: Try to open the same page in online IDE (such as [replit.com](https://replit.com/)), save HTML, and test your code on it **first**, before making actual requests, so your IP address doesn't be banned for some time or whatever else might be. When testing at scale (several thousand requests per minute), never use your home IP directly.